# Nesse caso usar switch ou if?

Tags: c#, .net, if, estilo-de-codificação, switch

Eu tenho um exercício para fazer que consiste no seguinte:

O usuário informa o salário, e dependendo do valor informado, ele ganha um aumento de acordo com a tabela. Exemplo: De 1000 a 1500 ele ganha 10% De 1500 a 2000 ele ganha 5% 2000 pra cima ele não ganha nenhum aumento.

Eu pensei em fazer usando vários `ifs`, mas no caso, seria melhor usar `switch`? Por que?

Comment: olá, já elaborou algum algoritmo para a tarefa ? explique em que consiste essa análise da média salarial, pois pelo que tens aí descrito, pode-se tomar diferentes abordagens, que podem nem ser as mais indicadas para a situação em questão, ou simplesmente forneça o exercício na na sua integridade.

Comment: Eu havia descrito de forma errada.
Então, o usuário informa o salário, e dependendo do valor informado, ele ganha um aumento de acordo com a tabela.
Exemplo: De 1000 a 1500 ele ganha 10%
De 1500 a 2000 ele ganha 5%
2000 pra cima ele não ganha nenhum aumento.

Acho que como o amigo ali em baixo respondeu, serão com vários ifs mesmo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não deixa muito claro  os critérios, mas provavelmente cada percentual  é aplicado de acordo com uma faixa de valores. Se for isto só o `if` funciona. `switch` não permite trabalhar com faixas, só com constantes.

Mas se por alguma razão seja possível reduzir para uma constante a partir de uma fórmula usando a média salarial, aí não só poderia usar o `switch`, mas talvez fosse o caso até de usar um *array* e  nem usar um `switch`.

Comment: Eu havia descrito de forma errada. Então, o usuário informa o salário, e dependendo do valor informado, ele ganha um aumento de acordo com a tabela. Exemplo: De 1000 a 1500 ele ganha 10% De 1500 a 2000 ele ganha 5% 2000 pra cima ele não ganha nenhum aumento. Acho que serão com vários ifs mesmo!

Comment: Então veja o [tour] o que precisa fazer agora.